# LCID of Standard Moroccan Tamazight

Tags: arabic, codepages, keyboard-layout, lcid

I have tried to find the LCID (for example, US English has the LCID 1033) for the relatively new language "Standard Moroccan Tamazight".
It uses phoenizian letters.

[image]

For some reason, I just did not find the LCID.

Can somebody help?
Thank you.

In Windows 8, it is called "tzm-Tfng-MA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it is 4191. I found it on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233968.aspx, using the "tzm-Tfng-MA".